Is ŚB 5.1.15 false and invalid?
Namasthe
Here krishna says the body we get and all our suffering is ordained and directed by Ishvara

ŚB 5.1.15
ईशाभिसृष्टं ह्यवरुन्ध्महेऽङ्ग दु:खं सुखं वा गुणकर्मसङ्गात् । आस्थाय तत्तद्यदयुङ्क्त नाथ- श्चक्षुष्मतान्धा इव नीयमाना: ॥ १५ ॥
"Translation My dear Priyavrata, according to our association with
different modes of material nature, the Supreme Personality of Godhead
gives us our specific bodies and the happiness and distress we
achieve. One must therefore remain situated as he is and be conducted
by the Supreme Personality of Godhead, exactly as a blind man is led
by a person who has eyes with which to see."

Is this sloka authentic and correct?
Because as per Bhagavad Gita verse 9.9 , Shri Krishna says I am not involved in any activities  and remain neutral

Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 9, Verse 9
न च मां तानि कर्माणि निबध्नन्ति धनञ्जय | उदासीनवदासीनमसक्तं तेषु कर्मसु || 9||
BG 9.9: O conqueror of wealth, none of these actions bind Me. I remain
like a neutral observer, ever detached from these actions.

So BG 9.9 contradicts with ŚB 5.1.15 . So does that prove that ŚB 5.1.15 sloka is false and invalid ?

They are not contradictory

None of the verses in Shrimad Bhagavatam are false or contradictory to the Bhagavad Gita.
